# Where can I find a List/Comparison of CIPA battery ratings for current point-and-shoot cameras?

Tags: battery

Where can I find a list or comparison CIPA ratings for current-generation point-and-shoot cameras? Looking for a camera that can last me a longer time on one charge.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly if you *only* look for battery life, your standards must be pretty low or you are very likely to be disappointed by your choice very soon.

I highly recommend you [search for the features you need](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?by=feature) (on my site)  and make a decision among suitable models based on important things to you, including battery-life. The search results show the CIPA rating of cameras (when available).

Just a note that the longest battery life outside of DSLRs belong to ultra-zooms: Fuji HS20/HS25, S4500, S4200, S3400, S3300, S3200 (Yes, the current ones are all Fuji). Smaller cameras *usually* have smaller batteries and last much less long. Even worse, modern sensors are much more power hungry than older ones. There used to be ultra-compacts with over 1000 shots-per-charge battery-life, all of them by Casio.